# Basic properties of weighted Sobolev space

Tags: functional-analysis, reference-request, sobolev-spaces

I am looking for some basic properties of weighted Sobolev spaces, like the embeddings, the weak topology, their dual spaces, etc. For example, if $\|u_n\|_{W_g^{1,2}}$ is bounded, is that true $u_n \to u_\infty$ weakly in $W_g^{1,2}$ and $u_n \to u_\infty$ strongly in $L_g^{2}$ for some subsequence? Is $W_g^{1,2}$ self-dual?

Is there any good book or note for this? Adam's Sobolev space book seems don't discuss this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a book titled “Weighted Sobolev Spaces” by Alois Kufner  1985